# handling images in an article stored in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building a website with a custom-rolled CMS.  For my blog, in the default view, I would like to display only the most recent post in full, followed by snippets from the previous 19.

My current method of selecting post information for the truncated posts is:

```sql
SELECT subjectColumn, dateColumn, LEFT(textColumn, 300) AS textColumn,
 CHAR_LENGTH(textColumn) AS length FROM tableName
 WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateColumn) < ?
 ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateColumn) DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

-- Yes, I'm using prepared queries.

I plan to compare the length of the returned text field with the associated value in the length field, and append a link to the full article at the end, if necessary.

The problem I'm faced with is: What do I do if the post contains images?  by using the substring function, I could end up mangling an image reference, whether I store it as a link to the image itself, or a reference to another table in the database.

I currently have a few ideas for solving this:

1. I might simply load the entire text, and cull any image
   references before truncation.
2. I could check the text result, before posting, and trim mangled references from the end.
3. I could load fewer posts, and display them all in full.

If anyone can offer ideas that I might be overlooking, I'd appreciate it

Comment: How are images included in the pages? Aren't they just <img> tags anyway? (easy to parse) Do you have a dedicated spot to store images or do you allow any source from the web?

Comment: I have not yet determined that, but since I maintain a table of images anyway (locations and stats only, not image data *shudder*) I would probably include them as references. i.e. [Image idNum]

Comment: There you go. Just filter img tags from output when rendering "snippets" ... at least that's what I would do.